# Problem in rendering bibliography in ConTeXt

Tags: bibliographies, context

I am using ConTeXt for making report and getting stuck in formatting Bibliography. 
Currently I am using these categories (via Zotero BibTeX export)
 `@article` `@book` `@misc` `@techreport` out of which `@article` `@book` render properly but the other two fail to render.

I could understand from the documentation http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf that they are should be supported but they are not getting rendered.

`sampledoc.tex` file

```
\setupalign[nothyphenated,tolerant]
\setupbodyfont[12pt]
\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,middle}]

\starttext

\usebtxdataset[sample1.bib]

\startfrontmatter

% coverpage
some context here
% titlepage

\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter

% ToC
\setupheadtext[content={Table of Contents}]
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section}, alternative=c]
\completecontent[content]

\completelistoffigures[method=dataset]

\chapter[intro]{Introduction}
This is sample i want to cite\cite[num][misc1]

\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter

\startchapter[title=Bibliography]
%intentional to generate unreferenced docs aslo for testing
\placelistofpublications[method=dataset] 
\stopchapter

\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

Sample bibliography file `sample1.bib`

```
@book{book1,
  title = {lorem},
  isbn = {978-1-5225-2194-5},
  shorttitle = {lorem},
  publisher = {someone},
  author = {john doe},
  month = jan,
  year = {2017},
  keywords = {Computers }
}

@techreport{techreport1,
  title = {lorem},
  abstract = {abstract ipsum},
  language = {en},
  url = {http://documents.worldbank.org/},
  author = {john doe2},
  month = dec,
  year = {2017},
  pages = {1-0}
}

@article{article1,
  title = {lorem3},
  language = {en},
  author = {john doe3},
  pages = {34}
}

@misc{misc1,
  title = {ipsum},
  abstract = {abstract of misc},
  language = {en},
  urldate = {2018-10-12},
  url = {https://www.something.org/}
}
```

running via `mtxrun --script context --autogenerate sampledoc.tex`

EDIT: Here is what bibliographic entries looks like. I was expecting entries 2 and 4 to render the same way as others. I guess ConTeXt is not recognizing them, or i missed to add some config.

```
1    john doe, Lorem, someone, 2017.
2    techreport: [abstract: abstract ipsum] [author: john doe2] [institution:
Tech Giant] [language: en] [month: 12] [pages: 1-0] [title: lorem] [url:
http://documents.worldbank.org/] [year: 2017]
3    john doe3, “lorem3”.
4    misc: [abstract: abstract of misc] [language: en] [title:
https://www.something.org/] [urldate: 2018-10-12]
```

Please note that `sample1.bib` is autogenerated by Zotero Better BibTeX plugin. It would be great if i can keep on using it.

I am on a deadline and any help to fix it would help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make up a minimal example of your bib file and your ConTeXt file?

Comment: @TeXnician updated

Comment: @Archit When you look into the manual you can see that `techreport` requires entries for `author`, `institution`, `title` and `year` but you forgot the entry for `institution`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster I tried adding an entry for `institution` in `techreport`. The bibliography entry still remains the same

Comment: Any help or suggestions?

Comment: @Archit In section 3.2 of the manual you can font he following sentence: `The default bibliography specification is very simple: only the categories book and article are explicitly defined.` When you use now different specifications (e.g. APA with `\usebtxdefinitions[apa]`) the `techreport` and `misc` entries get a proper style in the document.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Thanks you so much. I overlooked this fact. Works now. If you'd like you can post this as answer and i'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why only `book` and `article` entries are formatted is described in section 3.2 of the bibliographies manual.

> The `default` bibliography specification is very simple: only the categories `book` and `article` are explicitly defined. These were shown along with their default rendering in the quick-start example on page 4. We purposely limited this default specification as a minimal example for a bibliography.

To get a proper formatting for your other categories you have to load a different specification, e.g. `apa` or `aps`. To load another specification you have to use the `\usebtxdefinitions` command, e.g.

```
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
```